# Missing Required Module - Custom Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, clang

I created a `Cocoa Touch Framework`, this framework contains mostly Objective-C codes, my goal is to keep these objective-c codes private, so I added an adapter class in Swift as a middleman between the consumer and my objective-c codes. To do this, I created `module` to import my objective-c classes and allow my swift class to access these objc classes. I used this [guide](http://nsomar.com/modular-framework-creating-and-using-them/) and clang [doc](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html).

So with this I am able to access my objc codes inside my Swift class.

```
import PrivateObjc
public class SwiftClass{
     public func createPersonClass() -> ObjcPerson {
         return ObjcPerson()
     }
}
```

The code snippet above works just fine, within my framework atleast. But when I try to use my framework in another project, I get this error:

> Missing required module 'PrivateObjc'

I've seen similar posts here in SO but most of them are using Carthage or Cocoapods, some about CommonCrypto. This question is about a custom framework created from scratch. Can anyone enlighten me how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Try to set Framework Search Paths in build setting of your target - ${SRCROOT}/yourFramework

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately i get the same error, cleaned/deleted derived data and everything.

Comment: @janusfidel, did you figure out a solution for this problem. I'm facing the same compiling error. Thanks

Comment: @ScofieldTran did you find a solution. I have a custom framework containing other frameworks and I'm getting error: Missing required module 'GoogleCast'